# Safari: `all: unset;` adds a large number of css rules

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit

I have some very simple HTML that works perfectly on Chrome, but on Safari it does not. According to the web inspector, my span should be showing green text. However it displays as black.

[image: what it looks like]

As you can see, the name "John" shows as black. However, according to the web inspector it should be green.

[image: web inspector]

After tinkering around I found that the issue lies in my use of `all: unset;`. For some reason, when using `all: unset;` in one of the parent elements for the `<span>`, the computed CSS rules goes from:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(9, 112, 19);
display: inline;
font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
height: auto;
line-height: 25px;
pointer-events: auto;
width: auto;
```

to

```
-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-cursor-visibility: auto;
-webkit-font-kerning: auto;
-webkit-font-smoothing: auto;
-webkit-hyphenate-character: auto;
-webkit-hyphenate-limit-after: auto;
-webkit-hyphenate-limit-before: auto;
-webkit-hyphenate-limit-lines: no-limit;
-webkit-hyphens: manual;
-webkit-line-align: none;
-webkit-line-box-contain: block inline replaced;
-webkit-line-grid: none;
-webkit-line-snap: none;
-webkit-locale: en-US;
-webkit-nbsp-mode: normal;
-webkit-print-color-adjust: economy;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-text-combine: none;
-webkit-text-decoration-line: none;
-webkit-text-decorations-in-effect: none;
-webkit-text-emphasis-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-text-emphasis-position: over right;
-webkit-text-emphasis-style: none;
-webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-text-orientation: mixed;
-webkit-text-security: none;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: auto;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;
-webkit-user-modify: read-only;
-webkit-user-select: text;
border-collapse: separate;
box-sizing: border-box;
caption-side: top;
clip-rule: nonzero;
color: rgb(9, 112, 19);
color-interpolation: sRGB;
color-interpolation-filters: linearRGB;
color-rendering: auto;
cursor: auto;
display: inline;
empty-cells: show;
fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);
fill-opacity: 1;
fill-rule: nonzero;
font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-optical-sizing: auto;
font-size: 13px;
font-style: normal;
font-synthesis: style weight small-caps;
font-variant-numeric: normal;
font-weight: normal;
glyph-orientation-horizontal: 0deg;
glyph-orientation-vertical: auto;
hanging-punctuation: none;
height: auto;
image-rendering: auto;
kerning: 0;
letter-spacing: normal;
line-height: 25px;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: disc;
marker-end: none;
marker-mid: none;
marker-start: none;
orphans: auto;
overflow-wrap: normal;
pointer-events: auto;
resize: none;
shape-rendering: auto;
stroke: none;
stroke-dasharray: none;
stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
stroke-linecap: butt;
stroke-linejoin: miter;
stroke-miterlimit: 4;
stroke-opacity: 1;
stroke-width: 1px;
tab-size: 8;
text-align: start;
text-anchor: start;
text-decoration: none;
text-indent: 0px;
text-rendering: auto;
text-shadow: none;
text-transform: none;
visibility: visible;
white-space: normal;
widows: auto;
width: auto;
word-break: normal;
word-spacing: 0px;
word-wrap: normal;
writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
```

This is undesired, as the intention of using `all: unset;` is to REMOVE all existing CSS rules for the element. The reason being that this overlays on-top of an existing website, and as such can inherit CSS rules from the underlying website. I use `all: unset;` to avoid the underlying websites CSS rules interfering with this application.

If I simply add `-webkit-text-fill-color: #097013;` to my CSS rules, it will work as intended. **But I don't understand why adding `all: unset;` adds so many CSS rules when it's intention is to remove them.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into how the 'unset' property for the 'all' rule works, it would appear my assumption about it was wrong. [According to W3](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_all.asp):

> `unset` - Changes all the properties applied to the element or the element's parent to their parent value if they are inheritable or to their initial value if not